# What is the advantage to not use names, but only descriptions as unique identifier for lenses?

Tags: lens, lens-design

If I want to buy a new camera, I use its model number to look at review sites and videos, compare photos on photo websites e.g. flickr and search on price comparing websites and market places where I can find the best service/price ratio. I basically do the same as for tv's, power drills etc.

However, when I am looking for a new lens, I can never find a model number. What I can find is a complete description where every single part *may* be important to uniquely identify the lens, e.g. aperture, focal length(s), image stabilization, ed glass etc. On top of that some properties may be written different on different websites (e.g. `/f 1.2` vs `1:1,2`). Some websites add properties (like the color) and other just leave out parts of the description (e.g. `G`). However, if one of the properties is different I may be looking at a completely different lens with different quality, features and prices. To me, it is more logical to use a unique name, e.g. a model number. Since this is not the way the market has developed, there must be some advantage of using descriptions for lenses. However because I do not observe the advantage I am afraid I do not benefit from it.

Can somebody explain me what the difference between lenses and other consumer electronics are?

Comment: @Johan, turning it around: what (objective) answer would satisfy your question? Could you sketch how that would look?

Comment: @Johan, I doubt there's "proof" that lenses have names which is more than just peoples experience with lenses being named with their focal length (range), max aperture and optionally an abbreviation for some feature.
Also, glad to see you're looking to improve your question. However, before that I am curious what *real life photographic problem* you're trying to solve. Answering those questions is in the end the goal of this stackexchange. So what problem are you encountering? Are you looking for a site to compare lenses? Do you want to understand what the abbreviations mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. Am I correct in observing that lenses don't have names, or should I see the description given my the manufacturer as the only correct name, and is any variation on that a misspelling?

A lens is a tool, a part of the camera system. If I ask you to grab me a socket wrench, I’ve given you a useless description of the tool I need. If a ask you to grab me a 3/8” socket wrench, a 12” extension, and a 1/2” socket, then you now know what to grab for me.

Same with a lens. If I say grab me a wide angle, you’re guessing. If I say I want a 16-35mm f/2.8, you now know what I need.

These things don’t need names because they have one: lens. Just like with all tools, we select and communicate about them by their function.

> 2. In what regard are lenses and cameras different? Why does one have a clear unique name, and the other one not? My working hypothesis is that one is likely to own multiple lenses and want to differentiate them by their unique characteristics, but in practice I designate them with their purpose/reason I bought it.

See the tool point above. You’ll buy a drill press that has some marketable name to it but every bit you buy will be named after its function.

Have you seen the spec sheet for a camera? There are many, many features - a name that encompasses all would be ridiculous. So, they get model names to market them and compare them.

A lens has two critical pieces of info: focal length and max aperture - that’s it.

> Manufacturers ask extra money for a more silent/precise focus motor, ED glass, stabilization etc. so you can’t be serious to claim these are not important.

I never made any such claim. I claimed that focal length and aperture are critical to the shot, while the rest are "nice to have" features in the vast majority of cases.

If I'm going to a daytime soccer match, then I'm going to tell you that I want to have a 70-200 f/4 and a 400 f/5.6 with me. If you offered me a 70-200 f/2.8 or a 400 f/4, I wouldn't say no, of course, but I could work with less.

The fact that these lenses have USM technology or awesome glass is great, but not nearly as critical to my decision making process as focal length and aperture. For example, I'd take a manual focus lens with the right focal length and aperture for my needs over a super new and super cool autofocus lens in the wrong focal range.

So, yea, there are other features of a lens - but the focal length and aperture range govern the bulk of whether or not you can get your intended shot.

Comment: "that’s it" - Is it?

Comment: @xiota critical info, yes. There’s a bunch more of course but those two govern the use of the lens.

Comment: I like knowing the mount.  Maybe it's not that important since I see lots of listings that don't mention it, or mention a wrong one.

Comment: @Johan Have you really thought about the naming scheme you've implied?  What if you buy the Elijah lens, but don't realize till months later that you should have gotten the Elisha lens because the focal length and aperture aren't what you need?  Or maybe it has upgraded optics and motors you overlooked because it was too much trouble to bother with "every single letter"? (jah vs sha)

Comment: "focal length and max aperture... and macro" when available...

Comment: I like your comparison with drills and bits. The main reason I did not see the similarities is the price. If I cannot find the bit I want to buy I’ll buy another one because I’m not going home empty handed: I’ve got a painting to hang. But if the lens I want is not available, I am probably not going for the first lens with the same aperture and focal point. I want my ED/IS/USM/autofocus etc. They’ll get the job done, but so will a mobile phone 

Comment: @Johan Exactly, but think of the first thing you start trading off. Let's say you need a 50mm, so you go for the Canon 50mm f/1.2L. But, $1300 is a bit much so you look at the 50mm f/1.4. But, $350 is still a bit much. So you look at the 50mm f/1.8. Ah, $125 - that looks good. You're still getting a 50mm, decently wide aperture, while sacrificing some of those "nice to have" features found on top tier models.

Comment: @Hueco I just thought of this: let’s say you need a 18mm full frame lens but you buy a 18mm crop lens: it is not at all the tool you need!

Answer (score 4):

> Am I correct in observing that lenses don't have names...?

**No.** Lenses do have names, multiple names, like model numbers and FCC IDs. Manufacturers need a way to track what they make and sell. Some manufacturers also give marketing names to their lenses.

Since model numbers often don't convey information consumers need to determine whether they should purchase a lens, the specifications themselves also serve as a (common) name. Most manufacturers have only one *current* lens model with a given set of specs. Consumers can refer to lenses using abbreviated names, like "Nikon 18-55mm", and there will usually be only one current matching model. More info is needed when looking at used lenses, but it's not that difficult. If you don't remember whether you want the v1 or v2 lens, it probably doesn't matter. If it matters, write it down, or bookmark the review, or ask Google.

> ... when I am looking for a new lens, I can never find a model number.

Whether you are able to find the model number is a separate issue from whether it exists.  Model numbers for some manufacturers may be internal use only (not well publicized).

A bit of searching on the Nikon website reveals that the model number of a aforementioned Nikon kit lens is: AFS18-55_3.5-5.6GVRII_NT(7C_DL). Note that it is similar to the common name, without spaces and units of measurement. By learning the common name, you are effectively using the model number.

> ... there must be some advantage of using descriptions for lenses.

Common names (what you refer to as descriptions) are easier to remember than arbitrary model numbers. People are also usually more interested in the specs, which govern how the product will be used. Suppose a company were to introduce Elijah and Elisha lenses. Are you going to buy them based on their names? Wouldn't you be interested in the specs? Someone looking for a 35mm lens can safely skip reviews of 85mm lenses.

> I heard lenses used to have names but it got confusing.

Marketing names are confusing. For instance, what are the differences among Pancolar, Planar, Sonnar, Biotar, Biometar, Minitar, Lomogon, Xenon, Xenar, Hexanon, Hexar, Rokkor, Celtic, ... ? What if I told you that these names, *more or less*, refer to 50mm lenses for different camera systems? If you own only one camera system, just knowing that you want 50/1.8 is enough to get the right one.

Oops, two of those lenses are 32mm... That is the folly of relying on these types of names. You remember the name, but get the wrong lens anyway.

> you still need to know either the mount or the aperture to distinguish them.

It is not too much to expect people to know what mount they need for their camera. Most people at least know what camera they are using. Most salespeople can use that information to determine the mount.

> Can somebody explain me what the difference between lenses and other consumer electronics are?

Marketing names don't tell people anything about how the product will be used. For products like cars, televisions, and cameras, the use is determined by the product type. But the use of lenses is governed by certain specs. If you need a specific FOV, you need to find lenses with particular focal lengths. If you want to photograph at 1:1 ratios, you need a macro lens. Fancy names don't convey that information.

Comment: Noct is the name of the lens line, not any one particular lens.  You're free to lookup and use the model number, but very few will have any idea of which lenses you're referring to.

Comment: When it comes to mount, you need a Canon DSLR mount or a Canon mirrorless. There really aren't too many other options unless you're shooting film. That info is in the specs of every lens I've ever looked at. Frankly remembering the general category of my camera body is a _lot_ easier than remembering the specific mount designation.